# Ionic deployment build error with cypress in gitlab ci

Tags: ionic-framework, deployment, ionic4, cypress

I have a CI/CD process with gitlab ci for ionic app deployment for auto content update using this `gitlab-ci.yml`

```
image: cypress/base:10
stages:
  - build
before_script:
  - rm -rf node_modules
  - npm install
  - npm install -g tslint typescript

build_app:
 stage: build
 artifacts:
  paths:
   - /myApp/myApp-app/cypress/screenshots/
   - /myApp/myApp-app/cypress/videos/
  expire_in: 1 week
  when: always

script:
# run tslint
- tslint --project tsconfig.json --config tslint.json
- npm run e2e
```

The above step is used for build. But build is getting failed with the below error.

starting server using command "ionic:serve"
    and when url "http-get://localhost:8100" is responding
    running tests using command "npm run cypress:run"
    /bin/sh: 1: ionic:serve: not found
    Error: server closed unexpectedly
        at ChildProcess.onClose (/builds/myApp-ai/myApp-app/node_modules/start-server-and-test/src/index.js:68:14)
        at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
        at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

```
npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! mapsit-app@0.0.1 e2e: `start-server-and-test ionic:serve http-get://localhost:8100 cypress:run`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! Failed at the mapsit-app@0.0.1 e2e script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.


npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-09-08T05_50_39_435Z-debug.log
Uploading artifacts...

WARNING: /myApp/myApp-app/cypress/screenshots/: no matching files 

WARNING: /myApp/myApp-app/cypress/videos/: no matching files 

ERROR: No files to upload   

ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```